# How to check unwanted parameters in response body in Postman?

Tags: api, testing, postman, response, assertion

Refer to the below response body as an example, the only valid parameters of the response body are StatusCode and Message. We can add assertions and easily check if the fields are present with the correct value or not.

Now, I want to check if any unwanted parameters are being populated in the response and make the correction in this case. Is there any way to check this in postman using test assertions?

```
{
    "statusCode": 200,
    "message": "Here is the detail message",
    "data": "Unwanted parameter"
    "UnwantedLink": "www.unwantedlink.com"

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check keys using chaijs

```
const res = pm.response.json();

pm.test("check keys in response", () => {
    pm.expect(res).have.all.keys("statusCode", "message");
})
```

Example 2 cases below

[image]

Comment: Great!! This is what I was looking for. It worked for me. 

Thing is, if there are subfields, we need to put another assertion for those subfields.
Thanks @lucasnguyen17

Comment: You can explore the chaijs functions, I think they may have a function that deep compares keys of 2 json objects.

Answer (score 1):

use json schema validation :

you can use https://www.jsonschema.net/home to generate schema , click setting and settings and set options like:

[image]

```
schema = {

"type": "object",
"properties": {
    "statusCode": { "type": "integer" },
    "message": { "type": "string" }
},
"additionalProperties": false
};



pm.response.to.have.jsonSchema(schema)
```

Comment: This also good. But this will add more lines of code in test,  that I would avoid.
@PDHide Thanks for your answer.

Comment: @VikasKumar more lines of code != schema,  both are two different things . schema validation is for api contract validation and its a must when doing api testing